# 404 page deploy netlify

Tags: node.js, build, netlify

**netlify.toml**

```
[build]
command = "npm run build" # Replace with your build command
functions = "functions"

[[redirects]]
from = "/*"
to = "/index.html"
status = 200
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const router = express.Router();

// require middlewares

// require routes

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// Use the router to handle requests to the `/.netlify/functions/api` path
app.use(`/.netlify/functions/api`, router);
// routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hi there!')
})
app.use('/user', registerRoutes)
app.use('/post', postRoutes)
app.use('/images', imageRouter)

// use custom middlewares
app.use(notFound)

app.use(errorHandler)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000


// Export the app and the serverless function
module.exports = app;
module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

when the project got closer on the localhost, everything is fine, but I can't get access via /.netlify/functions/api

all default paths work

thank you for your time